# Fatal error came while using nativescript svg plugin in nativescript angular

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-angular

Iam developing android and ios application using nativescript angular.Fatal error arised when i was building my app in ios with the nativescript-svg plugin.i have an error like:

```
Users/admin/Documents/Transapp-03-04-2019/trunk/Mobile Frontend/transapp/platforms/ios/internal/main.m:8:10: error: 'TNSExceptionHandler.h' file not found with <angled> include; use "quotes"
      instead
#include <TNSExceptionHandler.h>
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
         "TNSExceptionHandler.h"
/Users/admin/Documents/Transapp-03-04-2019/trunk/Mobile Frontend/transapp/platforms/ios/internal/main.m:11:10: error: 'TNSDebugging.h' file not found with <angled> include; use "quotes"
      instead
#include <TNSDebugging.h>
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
         "TNSDebugging.h"
/Users/admin/Documents/Transapp-03-04-2019/trunk/Mobile Frontend/transapp/platforms/ios/internal/main.m:12:10: fatal error: 'TKLiveSync.h' file not found
#include <TKLiveSync.h>
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
3 errors generated.
note: Using new build systemnote: Planning buildnote: Constructing build description
** ARCHIVE FAILED **
```

How to fix the issue?

Comment: Try using `@teammaestro/nativescript-svg` instead of `nativescript-svg`.

Comment: ok i will try the plugin.

Comment: I got the same error with @teammaestro/nativescript-svg plugin

Comment: Both the plugins didn't show any build error on my end, but `nativescript-svg` was crashing at runtime and `@teammaestro/nativescript-svg` seems to work.

Comment: anyway to render svg image?